# How to get Jenkins old build inside Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I just tried to find out the old success full build in Jenkins, I did not find any way.

can any one help to find the old build in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a setting where you can control for how long or how many builds you keep the build history or the build artefacts.
If you still have the build in history but you lost the artefacts you can rebuild it from the same hash. If the build definiton and the build environment (jenkins slave) is the same, you should obtain the same build result.

In this moment all the build engineering good practices that you kept will pay of.

To help you more, you need to tell us:

- is it a UI (traditional) build definition, a pipeline defined in jenkins or a pipeline based on a jenkinsfile committed in the repository?

  - do you tag the sorce code repository (hopefully git) with the version of the build, or at least do you have in the build artefact the hash from which was built ?
  - do you store your build artefact in a repository so you can trace the history ? (artefactory, nexus, docker repo, GCP repo etc)

Comment: 1. it is no build from UI , build happens when we push the code to github
2. this part I am not sure
3. If I am tracing history, only very limited build is showing , I think some where we configured the limit of Build

My question was , if I builded one application last one month , in between that there are many build happens for other Application, here How can I get the last month build which had success ?

Comment: The only way is to know what version (build number) was that and where the artefact (build result) was put (outside jenkins) . Then, based on the metadata placed on that artefact you can investigate more. If the artefcat was only inside jenkins and the retention period is passed , you lost it.